# how to position a div below an absolute div in css

Tags: html, css

I have html structure something like this

```
<ul class="rslides transparent-btns transparent-btns1" id="slider1" style="max-width: 540px;">
    <li class="fluidratio" id="transparent-btns1_s1" style="display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;">
        <div class="bg thumbnail">
            <img class="thumb big" src="http://images01.inmotico.com/314/900/3149002000RC/580X420/b29e437f883ed50a71026a24cceb6f10.JPG" name="primary" id="primary" style="margin-top: -215px;">
        </div>
        <!-------!This div is for the discription in the image----->
        <div class="pie_foto">
            <div class="pagination_img">finca 1 de 14</div>
        </div>
        <div class="description_seemoreiii">Tels: 6107-2627 / 8669-8942 / 2573-9821</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then I have the relative css like this

```
.bg {
    background-color: #333 !important;
}
.pie_foto {
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
}
.pagination_img {
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
}
.description_seemoreiii {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

I am trying to add the div with class `description_seemoreiii` below the image and div with class name `pagination_img` on the image at the bottom . But I am not able to get it

I have created a [**FIDDLE** here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/UvL7N/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure why pie_foto was position absolute? Were you trying to place it within the image itself?

I've created a fiddle here where I've fixed it by removing the position absolute on the div with class pie_foto:

http://jsfiddle.net/richardsonweb/sqyPv/

However if you were trying to position the div with class .pie_foto within the image container itself, this would perhaps work better for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/richardsonweb/8Lkba/

In the second example, I've moved the .pie_foto element within the .thumbnail div:

```
        <div class="bg thumbnail">
            <img class="thumb big" src="http://images01.inmotico.com/314/900/3149002000RC/580X420/b29e437f883ed50a71026a24cceb6f10.JPG"
            name="primary" id="primary" style="margin-top: -215px;">
                <div class="pie_foto">
            <div class="pagination_img">finca 1 de 14</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-------!This div is for the discription in the image----->
          <div class="description_seemoreiii"> Tels:   6107-2627 / 8669-8942 / 2573-9821</div>
```

Then, I've made the .thumbnail div position: relative, in order to position the .pie_foto div within it.

```
.thumbnail{position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I was trying to add the pie_foto on the image and the description_semorii under that

Comment: Thanks for the help . I could not make out that I need to add overflow hidden and position relative for the thumbnail class  :)